# Set Click event on value display in Html file and want to show there child Element When Clicked on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, xslt, xpath

this is my xml file:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="final.xsl"?>  
  <root>
    <child1 entity_id = "1" value= "Asia">
        <child2 entity_id = "2" value = "india">
            <child3 entity_id = "3" value = "Gujarat">
                <child5 entity_id = "5" value ="Rajkot"></child5>
            </child3>
            <child4 entity_id = "4" value = "Rajshthan">
                <child6 entity_id = "6" value = "Ajmer"></child6>
            </child4>
        </child2>
    </child1>
    </root>
```

this is my XSLT file:-

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:for-each select="//child2">
    <xsl:value-of select="*"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="@value" />    
</xsl:for-each>
```

this is my html code:-

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
    xhttp.send("");
    return xhttp.responseXML;
}

function displayResult()
{
    xml=loadXMLDoc("final.xml");
    xsl=loadXMLDoc("books05.xsl");
    // code for IE
    if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        xml.addParameter("rss", test); 
        ex=xml.transformNode(xsl);
        document.getElementById("load").innerHTML=ex;
    }
    // code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
    else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
    {
        xsltProcessor=new XSLTProcessor();
        xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
        resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml,document);
        document.getElementById("load").appendChild(resultDocument);
    }
}
</script>
<body onload="displayResult()">
<div id="load" />
</body>
```

output is:-

```
India
```

now i want set click event on India... Clicked on India then its display There Child element like Gujarat and Rajshthan... Hide The India when show Gujarat and Rajshthan...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. First you can define your XSLT like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:param name="selected" />

  <xsl:template match="/*" priority="2">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not($selected)] | //*[@entity_id = $selected]/*" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[*]">
    <span onclick="displayResult('{@entity_id}');">
      <xsl:call-template name="ItemText" />
    </span>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" name="ItemText">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(@value, '&#xA0;')"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When it is run without any parameters, it produces a list of the top level items, with onclick handlers to call a JavaScript function with its own `entity_id`:

```
<span onclick="displayResult('1');">Asia </span>
```

and when it is run with an `entity_id` as the value for the `selected` parameter, it returns a list of the children of the item with that entity id:

```
<span onclick="displayResult('3');">Gujarat </span>
<span onclick="displayResult('4');">Rajshthan </span>
```

Then, you can write your HTML page like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script>
        var xml = loadXMLDoc("final.xml");
        var xsl = loadXMLDoc("books05.xsl");

        function loadXMLDocActiveX(location) {
            var doc = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument");
            doc.async = false;
            doc.load(location);
            return doc;
        }

        function loadXMLDocOther(location) {
            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.open("GET", location, false);
            xhttp.send("");
            return xhttp.responseXML;
        }

        function loadXMLDoc(dname) {
            if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                return loadXMLDocActiveX(dname);
            }
            else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                return loadXMLDocOther(dname);
            }
        }

        function transformActiveX(xml, xsl, target, selected) {
            var transform = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XSLTemplate");
            transform.stylesheet = xsl;
            var processor = transform.createProcessor();
            processor.input = xml;

            if (selected) {
                processor.addParameter("selected", selected);
            }

            processor.transform();
            target.innerHTML = processor.output;
        }

        function transformOther(xml, xsl, target, selected) {
            var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
            xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);

            if (selected) {
                xsltProcessor.setParameter(null, "selected", selected);
            }

            var resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
            target.innerHTML = "";
            target.appendChild(resultDocument);
        }

        function displayResult(selected) {
            var targetElement = document.getElementById("load");

            // code for IE
            if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                transformActiveX(xml, xsl, targetElement, selected);
            }
            // code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
            else if (document.implementation && 
                     document.implementation.createDocument) {
                transformOther(xml, xsl, targetElement, selected);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="displayResult()">
    <div id="load">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice how the `displayResult()` function now has a parameter, and when this parameter has a value, it passes this value to the XSLT as an XSLT parameter.

That should do it!

Comment: thanks its work great... :) (y) but here is one query i have fetch... when i click on  Rajkot... there is no child... if no child then its cant hide... whats for this? any idea

Comment: I've updated the XSLT above. Now it should only create the `<span>` for items that have child items.